# drupal comment module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

the comment-wrapper.tpl.php  has the following code.

```
 <div id="comments">
<?php print $content; ?>
 </div>
```

where is the variable form? when i looked the  template_preprocess_comment_wrapper function., there is no $content declared? why? thank you.

Comment: Did you want to theme comment form? Look this: http://systemseed.com/blog/how-customise-comment-form-drupal-6

Answer (score 1):

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_render/6 at the end.

It is directly passed to the theme function, so you can't change it there. This theme function is only used to wrap all comments into a given structure, a div by default. To alter single comments, use one of the inner theme functions like [theme_comment_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/theme_comment_view/6) or [comment.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes--garland--comment.tpl.php/6)